# Parse.com disable push notification notification

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging

I want to handle the push notification without showing it in the notification bar, what Parse.com does by default.

Parse.com **requires** the entry in manifest, so I can't change it to my own `BroadcastReceiver`, because It will not work.

```
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
            android:priority="1">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="packagename" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

So what I have done is creating the second receiver for the same `IntentFilter`, but with higher priority.

```
    <receiver android:name="packagename.ParseComPushReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
        android:priority="2">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="packagename" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And there I try to abort the broadcast

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    abortBroadcast();
    // handle here
}
```

But unfortunately, it I still see the "Notification received" notification in the notification bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually use your own custom Broadcast Receiver with Parse. It's documented in the Push Guide [here](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#receiving-responding/Android).

Specifically, replace:

```
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

With:

```
  <receiver
        android:name="com.example.MyCustomReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.UPDATE_STATUS" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And implement your own receiver:

```
public class MyCustomReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {
private static final String TAG = "MyCustomReceiver";

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
      String action = intent.getAction();
      String channel = intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Channel");
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));

      // Custom behavior goes here

    } catch (JSONException e) {
      Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've read the docs about receiving and handling push multiple times but somehow missed that point.

Comment: Is it necessary to unregister this receiver with this implementation. If so, where to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't figure out how to get this method to work for pushes that are sent from the web console instead of constructed from the device, and so the default "Notification Received" message still kept coming through.

What worked for me was adding android:exported="false" to the parse.com entry like this:

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.DISABLE_PARSE_PUSH" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.example" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
```

This disabled the default notification.